# Stored procedure not returning expected values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm executing the following stored procedure which returns 0 values:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_tblBook_DisplayReservations]

@bor_id varchar (9)

AS
    SELECT bor_id, isbn, bk_author, bk_title, 
            cop_loan_type, cop_status, res_date

    FROM tblBook, tblReservation, tblCopy, tblBorrower

    WHERE
    tblReservation.res_cleared_date = NULL
    AND
    tblBook.isbn = tblReservation.fk1_isbn
    AND
    tblBook.isbn = tblCopy.fk1_isbn
    AND
    tblBorrower.bor_id = tblReservation.fk2_bor_id
    AND
    bor_id = @bor_id;
RETURN 0
```

The desired result, of course, is that it shows records which match the where conditions' criteria.
Such records exist, yet they're not showing.
I'm sure my syntax's correct, so I'm completely and totally stumped.
At a glance, if you've suggestions, please tell.
I've linked my program here should anyone want a closer look.
Unfortunately, I think that's pretty much paramount to assisting me with this issue, but thank you at all should anyone read this.
The following link is my program which I'm working on in Visual Studio (.zip file -- feel free to upgrade the .mdf file/sql server if necessary):
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07002279584481194620

Please, if you have time, download my program and see if you can find the issue!

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Agreed. It's also a little challenging to interpret your code as is. Use aliases for each of your tables and explicitly qualify each of your fields. Ex: `select b.author from tblBook b`. I'm personally partial to LEFT JOINS, but that's just my preference in how I mind process data, there are other types that may be more appropriate here. The commas in your FROM clause though are doing a huge full join on everything, and that's not what you want.

Comment: Tag the dbms used, that code is product specific.

Comment: Change `tblReservation.res_cleared_date = NULL` to `tblReservation.res_cleared_date IS NULL`. In Sql, nothing equals null, not even another null.

Comment: @SandPiper saying "I'm partial to using LEFT JOINS" is akin to saying "Im partial to using flat screwdrivers to unscrew crosshead screws". Yep, it will work some of the time, but it'll go wrong eventually. Specifically when you actually INTEND to not return results where left & right sides both exist.

Comment: That's why I said sometimes there are other types that are more appropriate. All I'm saying is that in a vast majority of the situations I have worked in, I have been able to structure LEFT JOINS in a way that has gotten me exactly what I needed and I was also able to use it to easily explain to non-programmer coworkers exactly what it was doing.

Answer (score 2):

Change `tblReservation.res_cleared_date = NULL` to `tblReservation.res_cleared_date IS NULL`. In Sql, nothing equals null, not even another null.
Also, change the implicit join to explicit join:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_tblBook_DisplayReservations]

@bor_id varchar (9)

AS
    SELECT  bor_id, isbn, bk_author, bk_title, 
            cop_loan_type, cop_status, res_date
    FROM tblBook
    INNER JOIN tblReservation ON tblBook.isbn = tblReservation.fk1_isbn 
    INNER JOIN tblCopy ON tblBook.isbn = tblCopy.fk1_isbn
    INNER JOIN tblBorrower ON tblBorrower.bor_id = tblReservation.fk2_bor_id
    WHERE tblReservation.res_cleared_date IS NULL
    AND bor_id = @bor_id;
RETURN 0
```